# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Where: Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Flutter, no se por que razon me sale el siguiente error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

flutter doctor -v:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-arm,
> locale es-419)
> • Flutter version 2.8.0 at /Users/christian/development/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision cf44000065 (hace 2 días), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
> • Engine revision 40a99c5951
> • Dart version 2.15.0
>
> ```
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
>     • Android SDK at /Users/christian/Library/Android/sdk
>     • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
>     • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>     • All Android licenses accepted.
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
>     • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>     • CocoaPods version 1.11.0
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
>     • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
>     • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
>     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
>     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>
> [✓] Android Studio
>     • Android Studio at /Users/christian/Downloads/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents
>     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
>     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.63.0)
>     • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
>     • Flutter extension version 3.29.0
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
>     • iPhone 13 Pro Max (mobile) • E39A15EB-DD7C-4910-8C96-5FC1BF10E2CF • ios            •
> ```
>
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0
> (simulator)
> • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93
>
> ```
> • No issues found!
> ```

mi build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "<NOMBRE DEL PAQUETE>"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Ya he intentado eliminando el `pubspec.lock` y voler a hacer un `pub get` pero no me soluciona el problema, tambien intenté haciendo un `flutter clean` y un `flutter` pub get y nada, he intentado con:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
```

Pero nada de esto me ha ayudado, alguien tiene alguna solución?

Comment: Cuál es la salida de: flutter doctor -v

Comment: Scott ahorita actualice la pregunta con el flutter docotr -v

Comment: Juan, pensé que tal vez habría un problema con las licencias porque esta pregunta con un error similar tenía un problema de licencia, pero ese no parece ser el caso. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67690472/how-to-correct-this-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1

Comment: Jonathon, intenta actualizar su minSdkVersion a 23. Esto a veces corrige errores.